# SQS Lambda Partial Batch Response Failure with C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a Lambda in AWS using .NET Core with C# consuming a SQS.

My lambda receive a batch of 10 items per time, and I need to control what messages success and failure. If I thrown an exception all my messages back to SQS, but I want to back my queue only the failure messages.

I read the documentation, and there is a way to do this returning a SQSBatchResponse with a list of BatchItemFailure.

The documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting

And I only find samples using NodeJS or Java. I tried to implement in C# but it doesn't work. I returned a SQSBatchResponse but my message didn't back to my queue.

My code:

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace SQSLog;

public class Function
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor. This constructor is used by Lambda to construct the instance. When invoked in a Lambda environment
    /// the AWS credentials will come from the IAM role associated with the function and the AWS region will be set to the
    /// region the Lambda function is executed in.
    /// </summary>
    public Function()
    {

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called for every Lambda invocation. This method takes in an SQS event object and can be used 
    /// to respond to SQS messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="evnt"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<SQSBatchResponse> FunctionHandler(SQSEvent evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var batchItemFailures = new List<BatchItemFailure>(); 

        var logService = new LogService();

        var i = 1;

        foreach (var message in evnt.Records)
        {
            context.Logger.LogError($"Item {i} - MessageId: {message.MessageId}");
            context.Logger.LogError($"Item {i} - JSON: {message.Body}");

            try
            {
                // ...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                context.Logger.LogError($"Item {i} - Exception: {e.Message}");

                batchItemFailures.Add(new BatchItemFailure
                {
                    ItemIdentifier = message.MessageId
                });
            }

            i++;
        }

        return new SQSBatchResponse(batchItemFailures);
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sqs queue as a trigger for your lambda, try enabling "Report batch item failures" through AWS Console. You can find this by going to your lambda, and selecting the sqs trigger.

[image: aws console]